# preventing a DOM object from loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it is possible to set a display property to "none" and toggle it with jquery, but ultimately the object is still loaded, just not displayed. Is there a way to prevent a element from being loaded at all to save loading times? I am using the below code to toggle css properties but I want it to not load the element at all.

js

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
    $(".startb").css({"display":"inline-block"});
    $(".flashObj").css({"display":"none"});
}
else {
    $(".startb").css({"display":"none"});
    $(".flashObj").css({"display":"inline-block"});
}
```

my elements

```
<div class="startb"><a href="Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3"><img src="dbs/images/start.png" width="40" height="40" /></a></div>

<div class="flashObj"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="200" height="20">
            <param name="movie" value="dbs/js/singlemp3player.swf?file=Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3&autoStart=false&backColor=000000&frontColor=ffffff&songVolume=90" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <embed wmode="transparent" width="200" height="20" src="dbs/js/singlemp3player.swf?file=Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3&autoStart=false&backColor=000000&frontColor=ffffff&songVolume=90"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
            </object></div>
```

Comment: Do you mean for embedded/linked media? Such as YouTube videos/images and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete it from the page:

```
$(".startb").remove();
```

But it will still be loaded and then deleted.
So instead of delete it when not needed, create it when needed...

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because loading alot of flash elemtns on a page is hard on a tablet. For the tablets I just will direct link to the .mp3 file instead of having a flash player.

Answer (score 4):

Dont put the element on the page and create it when you need it.

If you have a html element in the html then its already there. This should not be much of an overhead, unless you have numerous versions of the element.

Comment: Not putting an `<img>` element on the page doesn't prevent it from loading.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9267835/20394

Comment: sorry mike note sure what you mean, is that a double negative?

Comment: if you create an `<img>` element and assign its `src` it will load regardless of what you do.  You can put it on the page, leave it off the page, whatever, the browser will still request `src`.

Comment: Also, I don't buy into the idea that double negatives are bad English.  If you can't deal with contrapositives you shouldn't be writing code :)

Comment: if anyone has this issue you could look at using a jquery plugin like http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 3):

Put this at the end of Your html file:

```
<script type="text/template" id="myContent">
    <div>content</div>
</script>
```

Then append the element like this:

```
$('#myContent').appendTo('body');
```

By this You will save time the element is rendered. But still You have to download the html.
Another way to do this would be downloading the content by AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX loading as follows, but you have to split then into three different HTML files and one JS file

JS

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
$("#container").empty();
$("#container").load( "startb.html");

}
else {
$("#container").empty();
$("#container").load( "flashObj.html");
}
```

startb.html

```
<div class="startb"><a href="Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3"><img src="dbs/images/start.png" width="40" height="40" /></a></div>
```

flashObj.html

```
<div class="flashObj"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="200" height="20">
            <param name="movie" value="dbs/js/singlemp3player.swf?file=Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3&autoStart=false&backColor=000000&frontColor=ffffff&songVolume=90" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <embed wmode="transparent" width="200" height="20" src="dbs/js/singlemp3player.swf?file=Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3&autoStart=false&backColor=000000&frontColor=ffffff&songVolume=90"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
            </object></div>
```

And your homepage:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Please tell me if you need any further help?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Some kinds of elements load regardless of what you do.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onerror = function () { alert("The browser tried to load me and failed"); };
img.src = 'bogus';
// img hasn't even been added to the DOM.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a server-sided language, such as PHP, to load the parts of the DOM. While it isn't always an option, it is far more reliable than a client-side script. The downside is that it may be more difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume there is a div element like this in your page.

```
<div id="containerDiv">
</div>
```

You can add your elements on page load by using the `$("#containerDiv").append()` method. However, I don't see the reason why you wouldn't do it on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy loading: so for example you put  in the html.. and you have a condition in your javascript to replace the data-src with src when the width changes below 768px. 
[some libraries for lazy loading](https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/)